# C# UdpClient Can't Send Multicast UDP Packet

Tags: c#, multicast, udpclient

I have a laptop which has a wireless adapter with ip address "192.168.5.60". This laptop will send UDP Multicast packets.

I have a desktop pc which has a network adapter ip ""192.168.5.90". I installed a software named "Multicast Tester" which joins multicast group("239.194.190.22:4000") on this desktop pc.

Problem is if i use another software which i installed from internet on laptop and send multicast udp packets to "239.194.190.22:4000" i can receive these packets in desktop pc.

If I use my program to send these packets, i can't receive multicast packets.

My code :

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
udpClient.client.bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.5.60"), 0));
udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse("239.194.190.22"));
udpClient.send(myData, myData.length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("239.194.190.22"), 4000));
```

Note : Both computers have multiple nics.

Comment: Most routers will not forward multicast without setting properties to allow multicast to pass.  So I need to understand your network architecture to be able to help.

Comment: @jdweng But, other software can send it. I'm not touching router configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it. It looks like default TTL value for UDP Multicast packets is '1'. !
I changed it to '16' by using this code:

_udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MuticastTimeToLive, 16);

Comment: What you did is dangerous.  You do not want to have Multicast broadcast outside the local subnet and that is why it is set to 1.  Muliticast is meant for a single subnet.  Now you may have a router/hub in the network and may need to set to 2, but 16 is problematic.  If 2 does not work then you need to investigate what the root cause of the issue is.

Comment: @jdweng: No, multicast is not meant for a single subnet.  That's broadcast.

Comment: @BenVoigt :What!!!!  Multicast is Broadcast is UDP.  Multicast usually only works in a subnet since routers do not pass Multicast by default.

Comment: @jdweng I've never heard such ridiculousness.  Just because neither multicast nor broadcast work with TCP does not mean that they are the same as each other.  Multicast packets are not broadcast.  Multicast is implemented at the IP layer, not by UDP.  And "routers do not pass multicast by default" is highly misleading; it suggests that they block multicast unless you change the configuration, when actually all that's needed is for the recipient to join the group (with an IGMP message).  The whole raison d'etre for IGMP is to support multicast beyond a single broadcast domain.

Comment: You are all wrong.  TCP is reliable since every packet get an ACK.  UDP doesn't get the ACK.  Since Multicast doesn't get an ACK it is UDP (not TCP).  You do not want multicast to get outside a subnet because it create a lot of traffic.  Broadcast is meant for a single subnet.  When you join a group you are using UDP not in the broadcast mode.  Broadcast is when you send without making a connection.  The Group allows a connection to be made in UDP.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, the problem is that your sender is sending out its system default multicast interface which happens to be an interface not on the link with the 192.168.5/24 network. If you use `IP_MULTICAST_IF` with either the sender's ip or the index of the interface (as shown by `ipconfig`) instead of `IP_MULTICAST_TTL` then the TTL of 1 is fine since you are then using the shared link, i.e:

```
_udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,
  SocketOptionName.MulticastInterface, IPAddress.Parse("192.168.5.60").GetAddressBytes());
```

(Where you may need to do some more work on the address to make it a DWORD in network order, and based on [ip options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/ipproto-ip-socket-options#IP_MULTICAST_IF) and [enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname?view=netframework-4.8))